# Why these series have the same radius of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I'm trying to explain why these two series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_{n}(z-a)^{n}$$ and$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_{n}(z-a)^{n-1}$$
have the same radius of convergence.

I know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_{n}(z-a)^{n}=(z-a)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nc_{n}(z-a)^{n-1}$ and knowing that I should know how to conclude that the set of points that both converge are the same, but I don't.

On the other hand, in most of the tests that I use I know that if some limit exist then the radius of convergence is this limit.

In those tests mentioned it doesn't require more than $c_n$ (which both series have in common) but if there is a radius of convergence I am not sure that it implies that the test should give it as a consequence, and because of that I don't know how to proceed. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you sure that the first series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(a-z)^n$ instead of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n(a-z)^n$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, I am

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos In fact, is a lemma that I want to prove before concluding than the derivative of the function associated of a power series is, in fact $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(a-z)^{n-1}$ and mantains it radius of convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, then a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if and only if the seres $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\lambda a_n$ converges. Therefore,$$z\neq a\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(z-a)^n\text{ converges if and only if }\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(z-a)^{n-1}\text{ converges.}$$Besides, both series converge when $z=a$. So$$\left\{z\in\mathbb C\,\middle|\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(z-a)^n\text{ converges}\right\}=\left\{z\in\mathbb C\,\middle|\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty nc_n(z-a)^{n-1}\text{ converges}\right\}$$and therefore both series have the same radius of convergence.

Comment: Does it matter if $\lambda:=\lambda(z)$ because in this case, depending of the chosen $z$ $\lambda$ changes, or am I missing something?

Comment: For each $z$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n(z-a)^n=(z-a)\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n(z-a)^{n-1}$. What else do you nedd. But, yes, you get a different $\lambda$ for each  $z$. So what? If you had a different $\lambda$ for each $n$, it would be another matter…